# How to handle this Data Abort exception in ARM 7? mode in CPSR 0x17 and board stucked at 0x10

Tags: exception, arm, abort

I am working on ARM 7 board and facing data handler related issues i.e. many times board got stuck at **0x10**. I checked CPSR register and found mode is **0x17(Abort mode).** How to handle this Data Abort  exception in **ARM 7**? I tried to configure in exception vector but it failed. Also the R14(Linked Register) is different at every time.

Disassembly

```
Next label is a Thumb label
FIQ_MODE:
USER_MODE:
--> 00000010 E59FF018 LDR PC, [PC, #+24]    ;D ABT [0x30] = USR_MODE (0x10)
```

Using IAR. Data Abort occurring after servicing many IRQs for long time.

Comment: you can determine the instruction that caused the fault from the lr, disassemble the code around that address and work back from there.  My guess it is an unaligned access, but might be something else.  you can examine the registers as well to see what they were set to when that instruction

Comment: Is there any backstrace option in IAR from address? As R14(lr) is different at everytime so can i manage it by exception handling? And Thank you I will try to trace.